# Bash Shell Commands with options

Tags: linux, shell, command, pipe, command-line-arguments

I'm having issues with piping the translate command into the word count command using the shell for an assignment. Using Debian 9 Linux distro.

I need to remove colons from the passwd file in the /etc directory and pipe the results into "word count" or wc -w. I have read the man pages, google searched and tried youtube videos, but could not find anything that would point me in the right direction. Things I have tried include:

```
tr -d ":" | wc -w /etc/passwd

tr -d [:punct:] | wc -w /etc/passwd

tr -- delete [:punct:] | wc -w /etc/passwd

tr -s [:punct:] [:space:] | wc -w /etc/passwd

tr -t [:] [" "] | wc -w /etc/passwd
```

The piped command is supposed to delete colons, replace them with spaces, and change the word count/"wc" commands output.

Before using translate and piping to wc, passwd's word count is equal to 37 lines, 60 words and 2054 bytes. I believe the number is supposed to increase when you remove the colons.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Piping and Redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9553628/608639), [cat file | ... vs ... <file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2552402/608639), [Pipe | Redirection < > Precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12942042/608639), etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the content of the file to `tr` first.

```
< /etc/passwd tr ":" " " | wc -w
```

Or with `cat`, even when it's a [useless use of cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat).

```
cat /etc/passwd | tr ":" " " | wc -w
```

Comment: note: this is a [useless use of cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat)

Comment: Thanks! It didn't occur to me that you had to redirect it to the file.  Still crawling while trying to learn the command line.

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like this?

```
tr ":" " " < /etc/passwd | wc -w
```

Comment: Thank you, that works as well, I didn't know how many ways you could skin this cat until I saw the responses!